# When connect to mongoDB atlas from java app running in docker get error no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell

Tags: mongodb, docker

6.3 driver and I am getting this error message.  If I run the app locally it works fine if I start it in Docker it gives me the error no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.  Any ideas?